# Java selenium - mobile eumlation screenshot - error "not connected to DevTools"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, mobile

I am using selenium 4.9.1 and cucumber 7.12.0.
On desktop view everything works. On mobile emulation I get the following error when I want to take a screenshot when scenario fails.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.93)
Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.16'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [bd62678bc5d0feaabd87666c9c090d8c, screenshot {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 113.0.5672.93, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae..., userDataDir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56115}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:56115/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 113.0.5672.93, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: bd62678bc5d0feaabd87666c9c090d8c
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:598)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:318)
    at stepDefs.Hook.afterTest(Hook.java:112)
```

Before method

```
@Before("@mobile")
public void beforeMobile(Scenario scenario) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//User//IdeaProjects/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();
    Map deviceMetrics = new HashMap()
    {{
        put("width", 480);
        put("height", 640);
        put("mobile", true);
        put("deviceScaleFactor", 50);
    }};
    ((ChromeDriver) driver).executeCdpCommand("Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride", deviceMetrics);

}
```

After method

```
@After
public void afterTest(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {

        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", scenario.getName());
}
```

Do you know how to solve this ? Thank you